# Installing new module

Tags: 8

I have downloaded and installed Drupal 8. The first thing I need to ensure when I create articles URL is automatically generated. In Wordpress this comes by default. But it appears not the case for Drupal.

I searched and found Pathauto (https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) will do what I want but facing difficult installing it. The page https://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/drupal8/module-installation shows a tab **List** with button **+Install New Module** but on my system when I visit http://localhost/admin/modules I don't see the tab **List** or **+Install New Module**.

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have this button, try to enable the module ***Update manager***.
Maybe this makes the button show .. What backend theme are you using ?

Here's the path to the module installation page: `http://localhost/admin/modules/install`

Comment: :D installing **Update Manager** didn't work but using /admin/modules/install worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Pathauto will do what you want. Download the module to /modules, and upload it to your server (FTP or via git).

Note that fastcomet.com is not the official docs.

Here are the official docs. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/extending-drupal/installing-contributed-modules

The docs say you must have Update Manager installed to see the link. I personally do not do that - but to each his own.

Comment: Installing **Update Manager** didn't resolve. But I followed advice from @rémy to use /admin/modules/install and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin/reports/updates install bootstap theme. Install and set to default. This should enable both the install theme button and the install module button. You can then revert to the Bartik theme or any other theme.